# How to get a specific column's text, when clicked on a table row with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I basically have a table with 5 different columns and 10 rows. I would like the following to happen when someone clicks on a `row`:

- Get the row's first column's text value
- Alert the value we got before

I have already tried somethng but it gets the actual column's data, which is not good for me.

```
$('.table tbody tr').click( function (e) {
    alert ($(e.target).text());
} );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "it gets the actual column's data", what is different from what you want?

Comment: I don't need the actual column value, I just need the first value ALWAYs when they click on a row. (Or second, third value, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.table tbody tr').click( function () {
    alert ($(this).find('td:first').text());
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I manage to get the second value by the way?

Comment: `$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text()` see this: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ 1 means second child becouse index starts with zero

Comment: also you can give class name for each column and try this, in case you change column order you would not need to change js code too.. `$(this).find('td.className').text()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var previousValue = ''
$('.table tbody tr').click( function (e) {
    alert(previousValue);
    previousValue = $(this).find('td:first').text());
});
```

> How can I manage to get the second value

You can use `eq()`, which is zero based, to get the specific item in the set:

```
var previousValue = ''
$('.table tbody tr').click( function (e) {
    alert(previousValue);
    previousValue = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text()); // second item
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I manage to get the second value by the way?

Comment: @Radical_Activity you can use `eq()`. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var selectedTd = $(this).children('td:first-child').text();
        alert(selectedTd);
    });
});
```

You can also substitute `td:first-child` with `:nth-child(1)` and then increment the number, like `:nth-child(2)`, to target other child elements you might need.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RxgwH/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.table tr td').click( function () {
    alert ($(this).text());
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need:

```
$('.table tbody tr').click( function () {
    alert($(this).children('td:first').text());
});
```